# how make context refer to specific resource?

Tags: java, android, view, android-context

**In View class**

`findViewById()` invoked in initializing view subclasses objects like `TextView`,`Button`,`EditText`

**findViewById() as declared in View class**

```
 public final View findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
        if (id < 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return findViewTraversal(id);
    }
```

**findViewTraversal() invoked in above methode as declared in View class**

```
protected View findViewTraversal(@IdRes int id) {
    if (id == mID) {
        return this;
    }
    return null;
}
```

as shown above if (id ==`mID`) return context which refer to this id  , that mean every time this View class invoked it return specific view

i cannot track `mID` object cause it use a lot in 22500 line class! and have no idea what it is

**Question** i know that context has access to all application resources, but how make context refer to this resource given id ?

Comment: "above if (id ==mID) return context", it's returning the view itself, not the context

Comment: how could this refer to view ?

Comment: You are inside a View, so _this_ is referring to a view